# Windows Server 2012 / RDP as Administrator

Tags: windows-server-2012, rdp

When I login via RDP to a Windows Server 2012 system and attempt any administrative task (such as managing IIS), I get the following error after typing the password:

[image: Screenshot]

What user role must be granted in order to perform this sort of tasks?

The user currently has membership to these groups:

- Administrators
- Backup Operators
- Distributed COM Users
- IIS_IUSRS
- Power Users
- Remote Desktop Users
- Users

Comment: Is 'iisadmin' part of the Administrators group?

Comment: @gtirloni, added more information regarding the user roles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open gpedit.msc
2. Navigate to "Computer Configuration / Windows Settings / Security Settings / Local Policies"
3. Ensure Administrators group is allowed to login locally and through RDP